# Simplify Oracle SQL: Treat null date as 'N' and non-null date as 'Y'

Tags: sql, oracle, null

This works, but nvl AND case seem redundant.
Basically, if null then 'N' else 'Y.

CHICKEN_HATCH_DATE is a DATE data type.

```
  select  stricken_chicken_id,
          case nvl(to_char(chicken_hatch_date),'N') 
          when 'N' then 'N'
          else 'Y'
          end chicken_hatch_date              
   from   stricken_chicken;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but if you don't like all of those `'N'`'s would

```
  select  stricken_chicken_id,
          case when to_char(chicken_hatch_date) is null then
             'N'
          else
             'Y'
          end chicken_hatch_date              
   from   stricken_chicken;
```

work for you?

Comment: I tweaked this slightly.. yielding select id, case when hatch_date is null then 'N' else 'Y' end .... There is no need to perform any operation on hatch_date.

Answer (score 4):

If your aim is to print N for a null date why not check that directly?

```
SELECT
    stricken_chicken_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN chicken_hatch_date IS NULL THEN
            'N'
        ELSE
            'Y'
    END AS "chicken_hatch_date"           
FROM
    stricken_chicken;
```

Comment: Won't this always choose 'Y'?

Comment: Well spotted - moved the variable so that the statement becomes IS NULL

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, `nvl2` is easier to read:

```
select stricken_chicken_id,
       nvl2(chicken_hatch_date, 'Y', 'N') chicken_hatch_date
  from stricken_chicken;
```

*Updated:*

- Corrected <kbd>.</kbd> to <kbd>,</kbd>
- Corrected order of parameters to `nvl2()`

Comment: This will not work properly.

Comment: @kyooryu I fixed a typo, the period after `stricken_chicken_id` should have been a comma. With that correction, this does work.

Comment: It will, however 'Y' and 'N' are mixed up - N should come when chicken_hatch_date is null, in your query it will be the other way round.

Comment: I've swapped the order of the parameters in Rev 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think that better approach is to use "decode" instead of "case" in this example:

```
select stricken_chicken_id
      ,decode(chicken_hatch_date, null, 'N', 'Y') chicken_hatch_date
  from stricken_chicken;
```